# How to convert string variable to int and vice versa in CLASSIC ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I am new to classic asp.

```
    MaxLnkApp=rsTemp("Info")

    MaxLnkAppCount=rsTemp("Count")

    if MaxLnkApp=MaxLnkAppCount then
          averageNum = 0
    end if
```

rsTemp("Count") is int and rsTemp("Info") is string

Even when the condition is not (like both variables equals five) satisfied.

How to convert string to integer? or Integer to string?

Comment: Does your recordset fields contain any data? Just use `MaxLnkApp=rsTemp("Info") & ""` to assume an empty string if null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question, as in classic ASP everything is a variant type.

Assuming that both rsTemp("Info") and rsTemp("Count") cannot contain `NULL` values (returned from the database) you can either use `CStr` (convert to string)

```
if CStr(MaxLnkApp) = CStr(MaxLnkAppCount) then
```

Or `CLng` (convert to long integer)

```
if CLng(MaxLnkApp) = CLng(MaxLnkAppCount) then
```

`CLng` is advised in this case (instead of `CInt`) because a SQL Server data type of INT is actually a long integer.

Comment: `Wrong number of validations or invalid property assignments: 'CStr'` This error is showing. Same problem with CLng

Comment: Then you should pinpoint what MaxLnkApp and MaxLnkAppCount contain just before the error occurs. This might help you decide how to handle the then expected error. As I said, my answer is based on the assumption that the returned values are not empty.

Comment: Should be using `IsNumeric()` to check the variable contains a valid numeric value before using `CInt()`, `Clng()` or `CDbl()`.

Comment: Apologies, but I disagree this is a good question. Classic ASP has been around 20+ years and you think that asking how to convert strings to numbers hasn't been touched on already? If not Classic ASP it definitely has in VBScript. The correct course of action would be to vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: @Lankymart I agree with your sentiment but I think we shouldn't be to rigid with newcomers. I also agree with your IsNumeric() suggestion, but is from the same cloth as checking for possible empty/null values.